# codeigniter Cannot access protected property MY_Loader::$_ci_cached_vars

Tags: php, codeigniter

After upgrade of Codeigniter i get this message

> Cannot access protected property MY_Loader::$_ci_cached_vars

i know that this property is now protected so i change

```
else if (isset($CI->load->_ci_cached_vars[$key]))
    {
        $val = $CI->load->_ci_cached_vars[$key];
    }
```

to

```
if (isset($CI->load->get_var($key)))
    {
        $val = $CI->load->get_var($key);
    }
```

but then i get

> Can't use method return value in write context

this is `get_var` method

```
/**
     * Get Variable
     *
     * Check if a variable is set and retrieve it.
     *
     * @param   array
     * @return  void
     */
    public function get_var($key)
    {
        return isset($this->_ci_cached_vars[$key]) ? $this->_ci_cached_vars[$key] : NULL;
    }
```

what can i do, just use

```
if ($CI->load->get_var($key)) != null)  {
        $val = $CI->load->get_var($key);
    }
```

without isset? i want to check if is not NULL, becouse `get_var` method return null

or is  `if ($CI->load->get_var($key)))  {` check enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `isset` on a function

i.e. `$CI->load->get_var($key)` will always return "something" - but what that "something" is depends.

So you are correct - the code below will achieve your goal. If the function returns "null" - then isset already failed. If the function returns something else (besides null) - then you will have a valid return.

```
if ($CI->load->get_var($key)) != null)  {
        $val = $CI->load->get_var($key);
    }
```